# PHP script issue

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I cant get `if ($register_user_name != $check_name){` to work, the nested if staement work properly though.

```
<?php
//al the default code to connect to mysql
include("../sql_information.php");

class infos{

    //the var that will store my sql query
    private $db;

    function login_details($queryresult) {

        //this runs the imported script
        $this->db = new MySQLDatabase();
        $register_user_name = $_POST['register_user_name'];
        $register_password = $_POST['register_password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
        //This is my mysql search query
        $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM `data_manager`.`user_accounts`;";
        //the result of the query is stored in this var
        $queryresult = $this->db->query($sql);

        //I dont know what I did here
        if ($result = $this->db->fetchArray($queryresult)) {

        $answer = $result['id'];

        $check_name = in_array($register_user_name, $answer);

        if ($register_user_name != $check_name){
            if ($register_password == $confirm_password) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `data_manager`.`user_accounts` (`id`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$register_user_name', '$register_password');";
                mysql_query($sql);
                echo "Registration Complete !";
            } else {
                print "The password you entered does not match, please retry.";
            }
        } else {
            print "This username is already being used !";
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing existing username check wrong way. You have to make database to do this check, not your code.

```
$errors = array();
$register_password = $_POST['register_password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
//escape string going to the query
$register_user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['register_user_name']);

$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM data_manager.user_accounts WHERE user_name='$register_user_name'";
$queryresult = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($this->db->fetchArray($queryresult)) {
  $errors[] = "Username already taken";
}
if ($register_password !== $confirm_password) {
  $errors[] = "Passwords mismatch";
}
if (!$errors) {
  $register_password = mysql_real_escape_string($register_password);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `data_manager`.`user_accounts` (`id`, `user_name`, `password`) 
                          VALUES (NULL, '$register_user_name', '$register_password')";
  mysql_query($sql);
  header("Location: cpanel.php");
  exit;
} else {
  foreach ($errors as $err) echo $err;
}
?>
```

Comment: @DiGiTAL don't try it to run, but rather try TO LEARN from it! Ask if you don't understand any of the code

Comment: Sure. it is redirecting to inexistent page called cpanel.php. you have to redirect user to some page after registrations. put there some address instead of cpanel.php

Comment: Even the password mismatch or username exist does not show any error, instead I get a blank page.

Comment: @DiGiTAL there may be some parse error. Are you sure you can see PHP errors?

Comment: I checked PHP.ini & it's all okay. By the way im on windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: try rewriting your code based on mine. and constantly check for errors. try to debug it

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Database Manager\install\registration.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Database Manager\install\registration.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Database Manager\install\registration.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

`$register_user_name` is a string, `$check_name` is boolean.

Also, by this line `$check_name = in_array($register_user_name, $answer);` you are checking thenever a `$register_user_name` is in array `$answer`. But $answer is not an array, it is something like an integer?

Answer (score 0):

[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function returns boolean value. So `$check_name` will be TRUE or FALSE, while `$register_user_name` seems to be a string.

UPD.

```
    //This is my mysql search query
    $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM `data_manager`.`user_accounts`;";
    //the result of the query is stored in this var
    $queryresult = $this->db->query($sql);

    // get result array
    if ($result = $this->db->fetchArray($queryresult)) {

    $answer = $result['id']; 

    $check_name = in_array($register_user_name, $answer);
```

I dont understand how your code work at all :) `$result` should be an `array('user_name' => 'some username')`. Trying to get 'id' key must generate a warning. Putting non-array `$answer` variable to `in_array()` function isn't valid too...

Comment: you aren't late. you both just fail to meet real life

Answer (score 0):

```
$register_user_name=$_POST['register_user_name']; // $register_user_name now contains a string
[..]
$check_name = in_array($register_user_name, $answer); //$check_name now contains a bool
if ($register_user_name != $check_name){ // if (string_thingy != bool_thingy) {
```

you're comparing two variables that have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a non empty string with a boolean will always return true as the string will be converted to TRUE.

Answer (score -3):

You can't do this.. It is simply just not valid:

```
if ($result = $this->db->fetchArray($queryresult)) {
```

I would say, that you need to put () around it, like this:

```
if ( ($result = $this->db->fetchArray($queryresult)) ) {
```

Let me know if it solves your problem :-)